# ASP.Net: Registration into MySQL server not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I press the Register buttun, it checks if the user already exists. If the user exist it will show an error and if the user doesn't exist it should register without problems.

I tried to remove the "UserCheck" and I were able to register, but if I leave the "UserCheck" it doesn't register.

The Registration void looks like this:

```
public void Reg()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int rndnr = r.Next(1, 9999999);
            string sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, email) VALUES (@id, @user, @pw, @em)";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = rndnr;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TUname.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pw", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TPass.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@em", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TEmail.Text;
            openConnection();
            cmd.Prepare();
            MySqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (mdr.Read())
            {
                ErrorLbl.Text = "NO";
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorLbl.Text = "You can now Login";
                HrefButt.Visible = true;
                Validator.ErrorMessage = "";
                ErrorLbl.CssClass = "text-success";
                TUname.CssClass = "col-md-2 form-control border border-success";
                TEmail.CssClass = "col-md-2 form-control border border-success";
                TPass.CssClass = "col-md-2 form-control border border-success";
                TPassRep.CssClass = "col-md-2 form-control border border-success";

            }
            closeConnection();
        }
```

And this is the "UserCheck" that is inside the Button_Click event

```
protected void RegisterBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username = @user";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TUname.Text;
            openConnection();
            cmd.Prepare();
            MySqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (mdr.Read())
            {
                string rr = mdr.GetString("username");
                closeConnection();
                if (!TUname.Text.Equals(rr))
                {
                    Reg();
                }
                else
                {
                    ErrorLbl.Visible = true;
                    ErrorLbl.Text = "User exists already";
                    ErrorLbl.CssClass = "text-danger";
                }
            }
            closeConnection();
        }
```

Comment: What does exception appear ? Also could you provide code of openConnection(); and  closeConnection(); methods ?

Comment: @OlegBondarenko Thank you for your help but I got it fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check existing condition with `mdr.HasRows` but not with `mdr.Read()` due to
 `mdr.Read()` returns true  if there are more rows in response. But if account record exists there is only 1 row is returned and   `mdr.Read()` returns false.

I guess this code might be enough:

```
                if (!mdr.HasRows)
                {
                    Reg();
                }
                else
                {
                    ErrorLbl.Visible = true;
                    ErrorLbl.Text = "User exists already";
                    ErrorLbl.CssClass = "text-danger";
                }
```

Comment: Thanks it fixed my problem. :)